# adding mysql REPLACE for joomla mySQL query

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have tried to add mySQL REPLACe keyword for my joomla query. below is the way which i used , but that code shows empty page. please advice where i gone wring

```
 $search = $this->getState('filter.search');
    if (!empty($search)) {
      if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0) {
        $query->where('a.id = '.(int) substr($search, 3));
      } else {
       $search = $db->Quote('%'.$db->escape($search, true).'%');
        $query->where('( c.parent_id BETWEEN 84 AND 107 AND c.level = 3 ) AND (REPLACE(a.title, ' ', '')  LIKE '.$search.' OR c.title LIKE '.$search.' OR  a.alias LIKE '.$search.' OR a.meta_description LIKE '.$search.'  OR a.meta_title LIKE '.$search.')');
        $query->order('a.featured DESC');
      }
    }

       }
```

Comment: Try adding `echo $query->dump()` just before executing it to see exactly what the SQL is

Comment: Issue found thanks for hint

Answer (score 0):

Are your brackets ok?

I mean an empty page usually means a php syntax error.
Set your site's error reporting to maximum, to make sure.
This is done by backend - > Global Configuration -> Server -> Error Reporting